# fail2ban port=https,http blocks only https not http

Tags: debian, firewall, iptables, fail2ban, ids

I have installed fail2ban to slove down the brute force attack to my hosted WordPress pages on a Debian 10 LAMP. The filters search for the IP and add this IP address to ipset. As it is, it catch some IP addresses, and it still works correctly, but my problem is that it blocks only https (443), not HTTP (80)

The filter is here:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> .* "POST .*wp-login.php
            ^<HOST> .* "POST .*xmlrpc.php
```

The jail.conf part about worpress:

```
[wordpress]
enabled = true
port = https,http
logpath = /opt/logs/*/access.log
bantime = 1w
maxretry = 1
```

And the wordpress.local looks so:

```
[wordpress]
action   = iptables-ipset-proto6[name=wordpress, port=https,http, protocol=tcp, bantime=604800]
port = https,http
enabled   = true
filter    = wordpress
maxretry  = 1
findtime  = 1d
bantime   = 1w
ignoreip  = 127.0.0.1/8
```

The iptables -L -n -v give me the next output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   16   868 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 443 match-set f2b-wordpress src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  354 21240 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22 match-set f2b-ssh src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

It shows that only 443 is blocked, 80 is not blocked. I wish to block both ports to prevent the redirection from http://example.com to https://example.com.
If I change the `port = https,http` to `port = http,https`, it blocks only the 80 port, not the 443. Have also tried to write the ports in a numeric way (443,80) but no difference in behavior.
Is there any possibility to block both ports (80 and 443), with just one jail rule, or I need two rules, one for http and one for https?

Answer (score 1):

You did overwrite a port value in the action entry (and did it wrong):

```
- action = iptables-ipset-proto6[..., port=https,http, ...]
+ action = iptables-ipset-proto6[..., port="https,http" ...]
```

so http was just another parameter name in your case, as well as it also does no matter, which ports you specify directly in jail now.

Also there is already correct, prepared for you) interpolation variables `action` and `action_` (e. g. see [jail.conf](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/753fff9c15387d62e32bc9794cb7a4714b9dd359/config/jail.conf#L212)).

Anyway don't overwrite it if you don't necessary need it... in your case it would be enough to set `banaction` like here:

```
[wordpress]
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto6
```

---

By the way, your regex's are extremely vulnerable, better would be to rewrite it more precise, at least eliminate catch-alls `.*`.

Comment: THAKNKS! Do you have a reference to how to set iptables-ipse-proto6 to ban ips forever? Will `action   = iptables-ipset-proto6[name=apache-custom, port="http,https", protococol=tcp, bantime=0] ` in the jail.local work? is that the right way to do it in 1.01? Or should we set banaction like you suggest and then change  `action_ = %(banaction)s[name =apache-custom, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s", bantime=0]` to add the bantime and name of the conf file with the filter that created the ban? Thanks!

Comment: no, it is not correct, for persistent banning one need to set `bantime = -1` in jail (this has nothing to do with action directly), but... it can introduce totally unneeded load by fail2ban and net-filter subsystem by a lot of non recidive evildoers, so I'd use `bantime.increment = true` instead.